# how to seed in Yii?

Tags: yii, migrate, seed

I'm wondering how one can seed in Yii a table once it is created with migration?
I've got a migration with an up-method:

```
    public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('users',array('id'=>"pk",
        'login'=>'string NOT NULL'));
    echo "table 'users' is created.\n";
    return true;
}
```

I've got as well corresponding **Users** model and its **CRUD actions**. When I try to execute another migration with an up-method

```
public function up()
{
   $user = new Users;
   $user->login = "Bob";
   return $user->save();
}
```

I get the following error:
**PHP Error[2]: include(users.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
in file MyYiiRoot\yii\framework\YiiBase.php at line 421**

I've managed to achieve the desired result by using query builder (by means of **insert** command), but I hope there is a nicer way out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
public function safeUp()
{
   $this->insert('users',array(
      'login'=>'Bob'));
}
```

You can also do update, delete and a host of other actions.  Look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration for more information

Comment: Thanks a lot! Once the answer is given, it seems logic. I must have overlooked this approach.